# Outlook API Using Refresh Token in Console Application

Tags: vb.net, oauth, outlook, console, async-await

I have a website that allows a user to sync their calendar in our system with the Outlook calendar using the v2 API.

Everything is working fine when the user clicks a button on our web application we receive the refresh token and store it in our database.

We have a console application that is set to run periodically to sync for the users so they don't need to click the button.

When I try to call the API anytime I await the response the console application just immediately closes.

Below is the code to fetch the events from the users calendar. The application closes on the "dim response" line.

```
    Public Shared Async Function FetchEventList(CalendarID As String, StartDate As String, EndDate As String, Token As String) As Task(Of EventListResponse)
        Dim EventResposne = New EventListResponse()
        Try
            Dim data As String = Token
            Dim baseUri As String = Convert.ToString("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/") & CalendarID & "/calendarview?startDateTime=" & StartDate & "&endDateTime=" & EndDate

            Dim client = New HttpClient()
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Convert.ToString("=") & data)

            Dim response = Await client.GetAsync(baseUri)
            Dim result = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
            EventResposne = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of EventListResponse)(result)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return EventResposne
    End Function
```

What am I missing and how can I fix it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was with the await not working on the console app. Changing it to call result instead works correctly.

So this code works:

```
    Public Shared Function FetchEventList(CalendarID As String, StartDate As String, EndDate As String, Token As String) As EventListResponse
        Dim EventResposne = New EventListResponse()
        Try
            Dim data As String = Token
            Dim baseUri As String = Convert.ToString("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/") & CalendarID & "/calendarview?startDateTime=" & StartDate & "&endDateTime=" & EndDate

            Dim client = New HttpClient()
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Convert.ToString("=") & data)

            Dim response = client.GetAsync(baseUri).Result
            Dim result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
            EventResposne = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of EventListResponse)(result)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return EventResposne
    End Function
```